# `Union` in a type definition for `List` items

Tags: python-3.x, mypy

```
from typing import Union, List


def homogenize(l: List[Union[str, int]]) -> List[str]:
    return [str(i) for i in l]


x = [0, 5]
homogenize(x) # <-- error, `List[int]` not compatible with `List[Union[str, int]]`??

y = [0, 'cat']
homogenize(y) # <-- error, `List[object]` not compatible with `List[Union[str, int]]` (OK)
```

`mypy` complains that `x` (`List[int]`) is not a viable argument for `homogenize`. It also complains about `y`, because its inferred type is `List[object]`.

`y` is exactly the kind of list I want `homogenize` to accept, i.e. I don't know if there are `int`s or `str`s as the items. Thus I typed it as `Union[str, int]` -- so why is a `List[str]` invalid?

In other words, what's the typehint for a list where the items are any of a known set of types?

Comment: My guess is it's infered `x = [0, 5]` as `x:int = [0, 5]` - try `x:Union[str, int] = [0, 5]` and see if that supresses the error?

Comment: The problem is that list is invariant, so even though `int` is a subtype of `int | str`, `list[int]` is not a subtype of `list[int | str`]. See also [Variance of generic types](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generics.html#variance-of-generic-types) from the mypy docs.

Comment: To see why passing a `list[int]` isn't allowed, consider this: what if `homogenize` contained `l += ["foo", 123]`. That would be perfectly legal inside the function body, since `l` is a `list[str | int]`. But clearly that invalidate the `list[int]`.

Comment: (tl;dr regarding variance here - you don't need mutability, you only need iteration, use `Iterable[str | int]` as a parameter type - permit as much as possible in args, restrict return type as narrow as possible)